# What's the difference between a C++/WinRT template console app and a C++ console app with WinRT NuGet installed?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, c++17

Here's the problem. I have a win32 (x86) program that has WinRT NuGet installed and working that needs to call a C# functions. I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/use-csharp-component-from-cpp-winrt#create-a-blank-app) and got everything working as a test C++/WinRT template app (see picture below). However, I followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/get-started#modify-a-windows-desktop-application-project-to-add-cwinrt-support) to convert a C++ native console app and a C++ native desktop app. Neither of these projects can reference the WinRT Component project directly like the C++/WinRT template can. So I found the output `.winmd` file and referenced that instead and got both native projects to build. But now I get a different error: `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered == 0x8000000c : A concurrent or interleaved operation changed the state of the object, invalidating this operation.`

What's the difference between a converted C++ app and a C++/WinRT template app?

Which part lets the C++/WinRT app reference the WinRT Component directly?

<s>For third-party NuGet packages, is this a possible method to use? Or perhaps I should look into C++/CLI wrappers for this? (I have no experience with C++/CLI wrappers)</s>

#### Edit

For clarification between the two projects I'm comparing, one is a `Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT)` which I think I got this option from the the [WinRT VSIX extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264). The other is the base C++ `Console App` (Run code in a Windows terminal. ...) that would download the C++/WinRT NuGet package after startup.

[image]

Comment: The "magic" happens inside the .vcxproj and .props files. Rather involved and with very little documentation. C++/CLI is completely unrelated to any of this. There is no CLR in the Windows Runtime.

Comment: `<CppWinRTGenerateWindowsMetadata>true</CppWinRTGenerateWindowsMetadata>` in the .vcxproj might be relevant.

Comment: @IInspectable  Oddly enough, I can't find that tag in neither of my two C++ consuming projects nor the two C# authoring projects (I made another authoring project using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/csharp-winrt/create-windows-runtime-component-cswinrt#create-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-using-cwinrt)). Although on step 3 of the link, it mentions `<CsWinRTComponent>true</CsWinRTComponent>`. It sounds like the tag you mentioned is the C++ version, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you call from a C#/Winrt Component inside a base Win32 console template app (not WinForm/abstractions/wrappers or using the C++/Winrt template)?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69321376/can-you-call-from-a-c-winrt-component-inside-a-base-win32-console-template-app)

Comment: @SimonMourier This question was more about the difference between the C++/WinRT Console template project vs a base Win32 Console app and adding the C++/WinRT NuGet package (see edit). But thanks for posting on that question! Your help is much appreciated.