# Can you call from a C#/Winrt Component inside a base Win32 console template app (not WinForm/abstractions/wrappers or using the C++/Winrt template)?)

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, windows-runtime, winrt-component

I have an existing program win32 (x86) console app that needs to call managed code (C# from a .Net `.dll`). The `.dll` is not exposed to COM, but can be called from a C#/WinRT Component and referenced by C++/WinRT Console Template app, **BUT** I can't seem to call it from a win32 x86 console app even after installing the C++/WinRT NuGet package. I've built and ran [this example](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/07/06/calling-winrt-components-win32-process-via-desktop-bridge/) but the consuming apps are always using the C++/WinRT template. When I try to reproduce the example with a base win32 app, I get the error `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered`.

I found [another example](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/) showing how to consume a C++/WinRT component from a win32 app, **without** registering classes. I thought this was my answer. However the process involves going into the application manifest and specify activatable WinRT classes by referencing the outputted `.dll` file whenever the C++/WinRT component builds.

Here's the problem: <s>C#/WinRT components **do not** output a `.dll` file, only the `.winmd`.</s>(see Edit) With the `.winmd` file, I can still reference the classes and build my project, But I end up with the same `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered` error. <s>I assume both the C++/WinRT and C#/WinRT components would compile into something that is in an Intermediate Language</s> (see comments), but why does C++/WinRT output a `.dll` and a `.winmd`, while C#/WinRT only outputs `.winmd` files? I tried to use [`WinRT.Runtime.dll`](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT#cwinrt-architecture) in place of the outputted `.dll` but that didnt work either.

I'm at a loss. I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69287900/why-can-i-reference-a-c-sharp-winrt-component-with-a-c-winrt-template-app-and) about the difference between the C++/WinRT template vs win32 with C++/WinRT NuGet package.

Main Problem: Can I use a C# `.dll` (not COM exposed) in a base win32 console app somehow?

##### Edit

I realized that I was using a C# Windows Runtime Component template that was specific to UWP. This might be why there was no outputted .dll when built.

[image]

Following Simon's reply, I was able to create a C# WinRT component that can be called from a Win32 console app. This C# WinRT component **DOES** output a .dll as well as .winmd. I followed a bit closer to [the article](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/) Simon posted about consuming with C++ and managed to get it to work with basic C# functions.

Comment: *"I assume both the C++/WinRT and C#/WinRT components would compile into something that is in an Intermediate Language"* - That is not correct. C++/WinRT compiles to native code. It will not produce a dependency on the CLR. It's strictly the compile-time metadata (.winmd) that repurposes the ECMA-335 file format to store type descriptions. I'm not familiar with C#/WinRT, its build model, or the artifacts it creates. I'm sure that it must produce an assembly holding the code, too. Maybe that gets compiled into the .winmd (which is a PE image after all).

Comment: @IInspectable well that makes a bit more sense. If the `.winmd` is also a PE, then there might be something I can do with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` means the class that you ask for (whatever it is COM/WinRT etc.) is not registered/known to the activation system (hosted in combase.dll).

The problem probably comes from the fact you're trying to use a registration-free WinRT component.

Let's take this sample as a start for the C# component: [Walkthrough: Create a C#/WinRT component and consume it from C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/csharp-winrt/create-windows-runtime-component-cswinrt). So, just create the C# component but don't create the C++/WinRT app. (I use Visual Studio 2019 and net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0).

Note: C#/WinRT does produce a .dll (here `SampleComponent.dll`), not only metadata.

If you don't build the C++/WinRT app, you still need to build a regular .h file to use the C# component. C++/WinRT does that for you, but since we don't use this tool, we must build it ourselves. For that, we need two other tools `winmdidl.exe` and `midlrt.exe` that you'll find from [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell).See also
[How to: Use winmdidl.exe and midlrt.exe to create .h files from windows metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/use-winmdidl-and-midlrt-to-create-h-files-from-windows-metadata)

So from the `SampleComponent.winmd` that you have if you followed the tutorial, run:

```
winmdidl SampleComponent.winmd
```

this will create a `SampleComponent.idl` file. Now run:

```
midlrt SampleComponent.idl /metadata_dir "C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata"
```

this will create multiple files (proxy, stub, etc.), but we only need `SampleComponent.h`. Now, create a standard C++ console app like this (I don't use C++/WinRT I still use `Wrl` to simplify my code, but this is not mandatory):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <wrl/wrappers/corewrappers.h>
#include "path to SampleComponent.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "runtimeobject.lib")

using namespace Microsoft::WRL; // ComPtr
using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers; // RoInitializeWrapper, HStringReference, HString
using namespace Windows::Foundation; // GetActivationFactory, ActivateInstance

int main()
{
    RoInitializeWrapper init(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
    HRESULT hr = init;

    // all error checks on hr omitted

    ComPtr<SampleComponent::IExampleClass> cls;
    hr = ActivateInstance(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_SampleComponent_Example).Get(), &cls);
    hr = cls->put_SampleProperty(42);

    INT32 i;
    hr = cls->get_SampleProperty(&i);
    wprintf(L"%u\n", i);

    ComPtr<SampleComponent::IExampleStatic> clsStatic;
    hr = GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_SampleComponent_Example).Get(), &clsStatic);

    HString str;
    hr = clsStatic->SayHello(str.GetAddressOf());
    wprintf(L"%s\n", str.GetRawBuffer(nullptr));
}
```

`RuntimeClass_SampleComponent_Example` is from `SampleComponent.h` and should be defined like this:

```
extern const __declspec(selectany) _Null_terminated_ WCHAR RuntimeClass_SampleComponent_Example[] = L"SampleComponent.Example";
```

If you compile that and run, hr will be `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` because the system cannot find the `'SampleComponent.Example'` component.

So what you must do is explained here: [How Registration-free WinRT Works](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/)

You must add a file to the project with the `.manifest` extension (any name should work with recent versions of Visual Studio), for example like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="CppConsoleApp"/>
  <file name="WinRT.Host.dll">
    <activatableClass
        name="SampleComponent.Example"
        threadingModel="both"
        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1" />
  </file>
</assembly>
```

`assemblyIdentity`'s `name` is not super important, what is super important is `file` and `activatableClass`'s `name`: it *must* be the same as the host dll name (here it must be `WinRT.Host.dll` which is provided by C#/WinRT) and class name you're trying to activate (corresponding to `RuntimeClass_SampleComponent_Example`).

You must also copy all the C#/WinRT files <s>mess</s> needed aside your .exe file. That would be :  `SampleComponent.dll`, `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll`, `WinRT.Host.dll`, `WinRT.Host.runtimeconfig.json`, `WinRT.Host.Shim.dll`, `WinRT.Runtime.dll`.

Note you can use C++/WinRT to help building `WinRT.Host.runtimeconfig.json`.

And now, it should work.

Comment: While I still ran into the `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` error, I think that has more with what I messed up on and less with your post. After I fiddled with the instructions a bit I finally got it to work (with basic C# functions)! I diverted from your post by using the C++/WinRT NuGet and integrating that way after trying all of your instructions. My next error is using third party .dll files, which ended up with `result = 0x80131524 : Could not find the specified DllImport Dll.` but I think that is a different problem.

Comment: @ThomasT - my answer specifically answers your initial question "how to call a C#/WinRT Component from a C++ win32 app w/o using C++/WinRT". If you carefully follow the steps, it will work.